# Is there a known issue with matplotlib.pyplot.subplots() clear and clf kwargs?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am running a script that creates figure and axes handles for a single set of axes within a single figure using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(num=1, clear=True, clf=True)
```

using automatic graphics (i.e. the figures show up in their own window) and am having two problems:

1. The figure doesn't actually clear when I run -- the axis frame and tick labels just get darker with each run.  Life gets really fun if I change the code to:

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   fig, ax = plt.subplots(num=1, clear=True, clf=True)
   fig.tight_layout()
   ```

   in which case each time I run the code the axes take up an ever smaller portion of the upper-right corner of the figure window.
2. If I delete the figure and re-run the code, I get an error:

   ```
   __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'clear'
   ```

   or

   ```
   __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'clf'
   ```

Things work fine if I run:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(num=1)
fig.clf() 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(num=1, clear=True, clf=True)
fig.tight_layout()
```

but that seems to be repetitive in a way that feels...dare I say...unpythonic?

For completeness:  Using Anaconda Spyder for Python 3.6 on a 64-bit Windows machine; will try different versions and OS tomorrow.

Edit: issue seems to be with matplotlib 2.2.3 as it does not occur with matplotlib 3.0.2.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example. So we ca test the behaviour you are explaining.

Comment: @b-fg The question does meet the conditions.

Comment: `clf=True` is no valid keyword argument. Where did you get that from?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I saw it at:
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/7023

Comment: That PR started off with a proposal to add `clf` as argument. At the end, this parameter was named `clear`. So `clf` does not exist as argument. Can you remove it from the code and update the question in case you still experience problems? Also please mention your matplotlib version and give details on *how* you run the code (type it in the spyder editor, then press F5? type it in the IPython console? What Spyder settings are set under preferences/IPython/Graphics?)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html

> Wrapper of Figure.add_subplot with a difference in behavior explained
>   in the notes section.

Looking at the source code, `clear` and `clf` are methods of `Figure`, so on the first call of `subplots()`, `Figure` object doesn't exist yet, it cannot call `clear` or `clf`. However, the second call and onward the object exists.

Comment: subplot and subplots are the tiniest bit different; subplots is at: 
https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html
also, this works fine the first time with a non-existent figure; it just causes the __init__ problem if I close the figure window between runs.

Comment: Same explanation seems to apply.

Comment: @DukeEgr93 Maybe worth posting this question in their Github repo.

Comment: the difference is subplots passes the rest of the kwargs to a figure call while subplot takes axes kwargs; I will definitely take your advice and see if I can ask this over on their repo - thanks!